# Save DrawingGroup drawings as an image on computer

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making a paint application in C# and all of the drawing is done in a Drawing Group. I've been trying to find how to save this Drawing Group onto my computer but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. Do I have to convert it to another format first?

Comment: You would usually draw the DrawingGroup in a DrawingVisual. Then you would use a RenderTargetBitmap to render the visual into a bitmap. Finally you would encode the bitmap into an image file by one of the BitmapEncoders.

Comment: See [RenderTargetBitmap.Render Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.render(v=vs.110).aspx). I.e. create the bitmap object, create a `Visual`, get the `DrawingContext` from that `Visual`, draw your `DrawingGroup` into the context, and then pass the `Visual` to the `Render` method of the bitmap.